# Plotting a System of ODE's Phase Portrait

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to plot a phase portrait, I think I need to use StreamPlot to do this,
$$x'=x(a-bx-cy)$$
$$y'=y(d-ex-fy)$$
I know how to plot this with manipulate

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a/c-b/cx,d/f-e/fx,0},{x,-10,10}],{a,1,10},{b,1,10},{c,1,10},{d,1,10},{e,1,10},{f,1,10}]
```

but i cannot get the vectors to show direction nor can i graph the nullcline $x=0$

```
Manipulate[
 StreamPlot[{0, a/c - b/c*x, d/f - e/f*x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  StreamScale -> Large, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"a = ", a, " , b = ", b , ", c = ", c , ", d = ", d , 
     ", e = ", e, ", f = ", f }]], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 
  10}, {d, 1, 10}, {e, 1, 10}, {f, 1, 10}]
```

but this gives me no image.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 StreamDensityPlot[{x*(a - b*x - c*y), y*(d - e*x - f*y)}, {x, -3, 
   3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamScale -> Large, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"a = ", a, " , b = ", b, ", c = ", c, ", d = ", d, ", e = ", 
     e, ", f = ", f}]], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}, {d, 1, 
  10}, {e, 1, 10}, {f, 1, 10}]
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 3):

The dynamics at the non-trivial equilibrium point:

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
<< c:\CurvesGraphics6\CurvesGraphics6.m
```

**Non-trivial equilibrium is unstable**

Non-trivial intersection of zero isoclines:

```
 a = 12; b = .04; c = 0.75; d = 3; e = .03; f = 0.1;

zeroisointersecx = ContourPlot[x (a - b x - c y) == 0, {x, 0, 330}, {y, 0, 32}, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 330}, {-1, 32}}, ContourStyle ->{Thickness[0.003], Dashed, Darker[Red]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], PlotPoints -> 100, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Tiny], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], AspectRatio -> 0.7, ImageSize -> Medium];
zeroisointersecy = ContourPlot[y (d - e x - f y) == 0, {x, 0, 330}, {y, 0, 32}, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 330}, {-1, 32}}, ContourStyle ->{Thickness[0.003], Dashed, Darker[Blue]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], PlotPoints -> 100, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Tiny], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], AspectRatio -> 0.7, ImageSize -> Medium];
```

Coordinates of the non-trivial equilibrium point:

```
P0 = {2100/37, 480/37};
point1 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Black, Point[P0], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}]; 
point2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.012], White, Point[P0], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}];
```

Equilibria on the invariant axes:

```
eqpx = {300, 0};
Px = Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Black, Point[eqpx], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}];
eqpy = {0, 30};
Py = Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Black, Point[eqpy], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}];
```

Labels for the non-trivial equilibrium and the four dynamic regions:

```
point3 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[P0], Text[MaTeX["P_{0}", Magnification -> 0.8], P0 + {3, 1.4}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
coordinate1 = {100, 17.5}; 
point4 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate1], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{I}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate1 - {0.3, -0.15}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
coordinate2 = {10, 17.5};
point5 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate2], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{II}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate2 - {0.3, -0.15}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
coordinate3 = {14, 6};
point6 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate3], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{III}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate3 - {-6, -0.15}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
coordinate4 = {100, 6};
point7 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate4], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{IV}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate4 - {-2, -0.15}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
```

The axes:

```
linex = ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {325, 0}}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.0015], Arrowheads[0.02]}, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2, Axes -> False];
liney = ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 31.2}}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.0015], Arrowheads[0.02]}, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2 ,Axes -> False];
```

Phase portrait:

```
icv = {{220, 12}, {100, 28}, {10, 3}, {170, 18}, {160, 22}, {28, 11}, {35, 9.5}, {260, 24}, {5.67, 6}};
Table[{{u[j], v[j]}} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (a - b x[t] - c y[t]), x[0] == icv[[j, 1]], y'[t] == y[t] (d - e x[t] - f y[t]), y[0] == icv[[j, 2]]}, {x[t],y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], {j, 1, Length[icv]}];
t1 = Table[{Evaluate[x[t] /. u[j]], Evaluate[y[t] /. v[j]]}, {j, 1, Length[icv] - 2}];
t2 = Table[{Evaluate[x[t] /. u[j]], Evaluate[y[t] /. v[j]]}, {j, Length[icv] - 1, Length[icv]}];
g1 = ParametricPlot[t1, {t, 0, 9}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, ArrowPositions -> {0.03, 0.4}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], Arrowheads[.02]]];
g2 = ParametricPlot[t2, {t, 0, 0.7}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7,PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Black, Thickness[.003], Directive[Arrowheads[.02]]}}]; 
Show[zeroisointersecx, zeroisointersecy, g1, g2, linex, liney, Px, Py, point1, point2, point3, point4, point5, point6, point7, Ticks -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**Population $x$ goes to extinction**

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

The zero-isoclines:

```
a = 10; b = 0.04; c = 0.75; d = 2; e = 2/375; f = 0.1;
zeroisointersecx2 = ContourPlot[x (a - b x - c y) == 0, {x, 0, 410}, {y, 0, 32}, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 410}, {-1, 32}}, ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], Dashed, Darker[Red]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], PlotPoints -> 100, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Tiny], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], AspectRatio -> 0.7, ImageSize -> Medium];
zeroisointersecy2 = ContourPlot[y (d - e x - f y) == 0, {x, 0, 410}, {y, 0, 32}, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, 410}, {-1, 32}}, ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], Dashed, Darker[Blue]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Tiny], PlotPoints -> 100, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Tiny], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], AspectRatio -> 0.7, ImageSize -> Medium];
```

Equilibria on the invariant axes:

```
eqpx2 = {250, 0};
Px2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Black, Point[eqpx2], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}];
Px3 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.012], White, Point[eqpx2], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}];
eqpy2 = {0, 20};
Py2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Black, Point[eqpy2], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large}];
```

Labels for the equilibria and the three dynamic regions:

```
coordinate5 = {21, 10};
point8 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate5], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{I}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate5 - {0.3, 0}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
coordinate6 = {140, 10};
point9 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate6], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{II}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate6 - {0.3, 0}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
coordinate7 = {300, 10};
point10 = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], White, Point[coordenate7], Text[MaTeX["\\textbf{III}", Magnification -> 0.8], coordenate7 - {-6, 0}]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All];
```

The axes:

```
solx = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (a - b x[t] - c y[t]), x[0] == 0.1, y'[t] == y[t] (d - e x[t] - f y[t]), y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, -10, 50}];
linex2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[solx]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.0025], Directive[Arrowheads[.02]]},ImageSize -> Large];
solx2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (a - b x[t] - c y[t]), x[0] == 0, y'[t] == y[t] (d - e x[t] - f y[t]), y[0] == 31}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
linex22 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[solx2]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.0025], Directive[Arrowheads[.02]]},ImageSize -> Large];
soly = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (a - b x[t] - c y[t]), x[0] == 0, y'[t] == y[t] (d - e x[t] - f y[t]), y[0] == 0.1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, -10, 10}];
liney2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[soly]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.0025], Directive[Arrowheads[.02]]}, ImageSize -> Large];
soly2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (a - b x[t] - c y[t]), x[0] == 410, y'[t] == y[t] (d - e x[t] - f y[t]), y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t,0, 10}];
liney22 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[soly2]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 2, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.0025], Directive[Arrowheads[.02]]},ImageSize -> Large];
```

Phase portrait:

```
icv2 = {{220, 12}, {100, 28}, {170, 18}, {160, 22}, {26, 7}, {35, 9.5}, {30, 6}, {50, 3}, {40, 5}, {360, 5}};
Table[{{u[j], v[j]}} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (a - b x[t] - c y[t]), x[0] == icv2[[j, 1]], y'[t] == y[t] (d - e x[t] - f y[t]), y[0] == icv2[[j, 2]]}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}], {j, 1, Length[icv2]}];
t3 = Table[{Evaluate[x[t] /. u[j]], Evaluate[y[t] /. v[j]]}, {j, 1, Length[icv2] - 2}];
t4 = Table[{Evaluate[x[t] /. u[j]], Evaluate[y[t] /. v[j]]}, {j, Length[icv2] - 1, Length[icv2]}];
g3 = ParametricPlot[t3, {t, 0, 9}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Arrowheads[.02]], ImageSize -> Large];
g4 = ParametricPlot[t4, {t, 0, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All, Oriented -> True, HowManyArrows -> 1, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.0025], Directive[Arrowheads[.02]]}}, ImageSize -> Large];
Show[zeroisointersecx2, zeroisointersecy2, g3, g4, linex2, linex22, liney2, liney22, Px2, Px3, Py2, point8, point9, point10, RotateLabel -> True, FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\text{Population}\\hspace{0.1cm}x", Magnification -> 0.9], MaTeX["\\text{Population}\\hspace{0.1cm}y", Magnification -> 0.9]}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**Population $y$ goes to extinction**

```
a = 22; b = 1/10; c = 75/100; d = 15/10; e = 1/100; f = 1/10;
```

**Non-trivial equilibrium is stable**

```
a = 22; b = 3/10; c = 75/100; d = 15/10; e = 6/1000; f = 1/10;
```

The qualitative analysis of this system is trivial. However, I recommend reviewing the book [Population Biology (Alan Hastings)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2731-9).

For more details about CurvesGraphics6 see:
[Gianluca Gorni](https://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html)

For more details about MaTeX see: [Szabolcs Horvát](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX)

Comment: Can you, please, provide a means to obtain the code you use in this answer? It will be better if it can be self contained. As it is now, this does not seem to be of use to anyone without the seemingly custom code you load.